# What is the simplest way to edit CSS variables with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-variables

I have been able to edit CSS variables with `document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--text-color", "#333")` however, I haven't been able to reproduce this with jQuery, the `.css()` prototype only seems to work with known CSS properties.

Here is example CSS for the above CSS variable.

```
:root {
  --text-color: #888;
}

div {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

Comment: $("element").css("color", "#888")

Comment: @Bindrid CSS variables, not generic CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: oh, have you tried righting them as an attribute?

Comment: @Bindrid I was able to get it working with `$("html").attr("style", "--text-color", "#333")`, though since I am using JS variables to fill in the property name and value, I would either have to - _since I am using multiple CSS variables_ - get the current style attr value and append the new var and value, hard code each variable I'd like to change or I'd have to do some magic with looping through values and inputs needed. So it does work, but is very clunky compared to the vanilla JS `document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--text-color", "#333")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of March 16, 2017, support for custom properties has been shipped in [jQuery 3.2.0 and later](https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/16/jquery-3-2-0-is-out). There are no plans to backport this functionality to 2.x or earlier, so if you need to use an older version of jQuery for maintenance reasons, you'll need to continue using the built-in `style` object to access your custom properties.

---

jQuery does not support custom properties yet. There's a [pull request](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/3199) that has yet to be reviewed (but based on recent comments appears to be slated for a near upcoming version). Priority is not that high though, as custom properties are still a fairly new feature and their nature makes both developing a wrapper for browsers that support them natively, re-implementing them in JavaScript for browsers that don't, *and* testing the feature to make sure everything works without breaking other jQuery features as well as existing sites, quite a task.